# why my rest interface return "{ "error": "no response from server" }" after configed by api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-cloud

I design a new api with api manager. when I invoked it in api console, it prompted the msg as the belowling jpg.

[image: look at the jpg ,plz, Those is the following logs after do curl as the folloing]

curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 8dfb0253-5906-3ee5-ab28-cd53bc190ddc' 'http://172.17.0.1:8280/V2.0.0/common/test/test'

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: why there is on reply??

Comment: can you try the same cur and get the result?

Comment: in the image you can see a curl command that API manager sends. So you can directly call it and check if you get the intended results

Comment: plz ,look at the above log image.

Comment: According to ur curl command output the resource doesn't exist. Can you check are you using the correct url?

Comment: @mike wire log clearly shows that request(GET /Demosite/common/test/test)goes from apimanager to backend and backend return 404 response. So please make sure you call the backend via ESB in the right way.

Comment: [2016-12-27 04:48:58,523] DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-2 >> GET /DemoSite/common/test/test HTTP/1.1 [2016-12-27 04:48:58,524] DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-2 >> Accept: application/json [2016-12-27 04:48:58,524] DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-2 >> Host: demo.vname.biz:8989 [2016-12-27 04:48:58,524] DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-2 >> Connection: Keep-Alive why the url is more than a "/test" ? my real url is "/DemoSIte/common/test"

Comment: I use curl and it also does not work. Through api manager , the backend url was changed "/DemoSite/common/test/*" , But , There is no real backend url which is "/DemoSite/common/test/*"

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is the problem having 2 `test` in url? If yes, post a screenshot of API resources in publisher.

Answer (score 2):

Possible reasons for the issue and solutions

1. Gatway uses https and self singed certificated. Type the gateway url in browser and accept the certificate then try with api console
2. CORS issue. Enable CORS as described in doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-Cross-originresourcesharing

Comment: were you able to invoke api from any rest client like curl ? can you enable wirelog and post the log to question, using wire log you can check whether request hits the apim gw and response come out gw http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: 2016-12-27 03:00:44,792 [-] [Timer-11]  WARN SynapseAppDeployerDSComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.service.MessageProcessorDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.message.store.service.MessageStoreDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyDeployerService,
 this is the log in wso2-apigw-errors.log after I do "curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 8dfb0253-5906-3ee5-ab28-cd53bc190ddc' 'http://172.17.0.1:8280/V2.0.0/common/test/test'"